# Spring Do I need to use an EventListener instead of Async?

Tags: spring-boot, events, spring-transactions, spring-async

I am working with an application that uses Spring's `ApplicationEventPublisher` to publish messages. We will have functions that do some complex read/update functionality against an rdbms and then publish that message to do work like emailing users or even publishing sqs messages for other microservices.

```
ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
UpdateEvent event = UpdateEvent.builder().eventSource("SomeUpdate")
                    .scenarioId(scenarioId).build();
eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
```

and a listener:

```
public interface LocalMessageHandlingAsyncService {

    @TransactionalEventListener
    void publishUpdateEvent(UpdateEvent mediaPlanUpdateEvent);
```

Because some of the events will do reads against the database around the data that was just worked on we use the `@TransactionalEventListener` to make sure we work on the latest committed data. As I look at this type of pattern I wonder what the advantage of this is versus just calling a separate async method?

With an async method we don't have to worry about serializing objects to json or creating separate Event objects to manage. We still have to worry about open transactions, but that is solvable, I believe, using the TransactionSynchronizationManager.

As far as I can tell the advantage to using events over a call to an async method is that multiple areas of the application might want to listen for the event. That does not match our use case however, as we just have one consumer.

Answer (score 1):

As you've mentioned, with a single consumer, this design pattern does not bring much to the table.

However, I'll suggest something else: [Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html)

Using Spring Integration, you can create pipelines and actually integrate the tasks such as emailing users and publishing the message to SQS to other microservices natively. This enables you to:

1. Transform and process a message in between service tasks in a single application
2. In case it's needed, use a message broker such as RabbitMQ to handle the distribution of the very same message in 1. to a distributed environment (i.e. The service in 3. might be running on a different machine, etc. Or you can send and forget)
3. And in one of your service tasks, you can actually send emails, etc.

Comment: Hmm, this seems like even more overhead and engineering than publishing an event! I think an Async method is still preferable here

Comment: It depends on your apetite for integrating Spring into your architecture. If you're not willing to be more Spring dependent, then yes, even a simple async might be the way to go.